# Maximum number of additional attributes can be added using 'ext' in Sitecore CDP?

Tags: cdp

I'm exploring Sitecore CDP capabilities and want to know about the maximum number of recommended values for additional attributes that can be added using 'ext' as key-value pair in Sitecore CDP.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As per Sitecore documents - https://doc.sitecore.com/cdp/en/developers/sitecore-customer-data-platform--data-model-2-1/send-additional-event-data-to-sitecore-cdp.html
below is a list of guidelines for using the events data extension:

- Only one data extension per event type is supported.
- The name of the event data extension must be ext.
- The key of the event data extensions must be default.
- The attribute name must be alphanumeric [A-Z,a-z,0-9] as per the json rfc7159 spec.
- The attribute name of the event data extension must be written in camelCase.
- The attribute name must be unique within the entire event type.
- The attribute name of the event data extension must be meaningful. Consider using the friendlyID.
- If grouping is required, use common prefixes.
- **An event data extension has a maximum of 50 attributes.**

Answer (score 2):

From your JSON example it looks like you are trying to add extension attributes to the guest data model. If that's the case then the maximum number of attributes is 100.

Sitecore CDP supports data extension attributes for guests, events and orders data models, and they have different limits:

- **guest** data extension can have a maximum of **100 attributes** ([link](https://doc.sitecore.com/cdp/en/developers/api/index-en.html#UUID-37105c09-e733-29cc-171f-fd40914603ac))
- **event** data extension can have a maximum of **50 attributes** ([link](https://doc.sitecore.com/cdp/en/developers/api/index-en.html#UUID-73a0059c-1daa-b272-80d9-d4e0c35783d9))
- **order** data extension can have a maximum of **50 attributes** ([link](https://doc.sitecore.com/cdp/en/developers/api/index-en.html#UUID-c27ea22d-771c-8021-e8d3-8b15e4ab88e2))

**UPDATE:** I changed documentation links above to point to the new Engage library documentation because the old links no longer work.

Comment: Thank you Anna for your answer with further details on guest/order data extension. it is also accepted with Mahendra's answer.